# How to get a box to appear from the top of the browser window on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a box to appear from the top of the browser window upon page load.

Ideally it would look like this:

http://demo.cookieconsent.silktide.com/

So the page loads and this slides down.

How would I achieve this?

I have looked at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ but it doesn't do the above it seems.

Comment: So have one. What is your question?

Comment: What have you tried?
+1 to Bergi, stackoverflow is not a place where other people code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/srFKa/3/)

In this example, I created a div that is fixed on top of the window but is hidden at first, then it shown with a slide down animation on page load.

hope this helps

UPDATED DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/srFKa/3/)

Comment: Thank you for this. I love the slide up feature you added.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

**html**

```
<div id="box"><h1 style="text-align:center">content goes here</h1></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").animate({top:"0px"},"slow");
});
```

**css**

```
background:red;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:60px;
top:-60px
```

**On whole the code is-**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<style>
#box
{
background:red;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:60px;
top:-60px
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box").animate({top:"0px"},"slow");
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="box"><h1 style="text-align:center">content goes here</h1></div>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
rest page content<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `<div>` in your html, set its css to `position: fixed` and your're done.